# Optimizations for bubble sort

Tags: performance, c, sorting

The code performs bubble sort on the basis if any swaps has been performed in the iteration. I made it sort of independent of number of iterations as in any conventional bubble sorting code.

I went on pretty much with what I understood from the cs50 class. This mechanism looks more intuitive to me. What improvements I need to do on the design/style/method?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printMyArray(int a[],int n);

//BUBBLE SORT
int main(){
    int a[] = {-1 , 2 , 0 , -3 , 5 , 1};
    int n = 6;
    for(;;){

       int swap = 0;
       int i = 0;

       for(; i < n-1; i++)
          if( a[i+1] <= a[i]){
              int temp = a[i+1];
              a[i+1] = a[i];
              a[i] = temp;
              swap = 1;
           }
       if(swap == 0)
           break;
    }
    printMyArray(a,6);

}
void printMyArray(int a[],int n){
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < n ; i++)
     printf("%d\t",a[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: One obvious optimization: [Don't use bubblesort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370829/bubblesort-over-other-sorting-algorithms)!

Comment: I get the point but I am asking in terms of improving the above scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Function**

1. Certainly no reason to swap when values are equal.  In worse case of array `{3,3,3,3}`, leads to infinite loop.

   ```
   //if( a[i+1] <= a[i]){
   if(a[i+1] < a[i]) {
   ```
2. Use `size_t` to index arrays.

   ```
   // void printMyArray(int a[],int n){
   void printMyArray(int a[], size_t n) {
   ```

**Style**

1. Rather than `int` for Boolean variables use `bool`.

   ```
   #include <stdbool.h>

   // int swap = 0;
   bool swap = false;
   ```
2. Recommend `const` when able.  Adds clarity to the function and allows for optimizations with some compilers.

   ```
   // void printMyArray(int a[],int n){
   void printMyArray(const int a[], int n) {
   ```
3. Minor: prefer `int *a` rather than `int a[]` as argument in `printMyArray()`.
4. More useful to separate `main()` from the code under test.  Something like:

   ```
   int main(void) {
       int a[] = {-1 , 2 , 0 , -3 , 5 , 1};
       bubble_sort(a, sizeof a/ sizeof a[0]);
       printMyArray(a, sizeof a/ sizeof a[0]);
       return 0;     
   }
   ```
5. Suggest fully `{}` blocks.  Use Idiomatic `for()`, Avoid  `n-1`, as `size_t n` may be 0.

   ```
      // int i = 0;
      // for(; i < n-1; i++)

      for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(a[i] < a[i-1]) {
          int temp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[i-1];
          a[i-1] = temp;
          swap = 1;
        }
      }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug though.